# Configuring X-Frame-Options to allow embedding my site

Tags: iframe, nginx, x-frame-options

I have a website, say http://mysite-a.com hosted, which runs on nginx.

I have another website, http://mysite-b.com, where I intend to embed a page http://mysite-a.com/embeddable.

In the nginx configuration in http://mysite-a.com, I have set the following:

```
add_header X-Frame-Options "ALLOW-FROM http://mysite-b.com";
```

However, when I go to my page at http://mysite-b.com, I see the following error:

> Multiple 'X-Frame-Options' headers with conflicting values
>   ('SAMEORIGIN, ALLOW-FROM http://mysite-b.com') encountered when
>   loading 'http://mysite-a.com/embeddable'. Falling back to 'DENY'.

Any suggestions on what I am doing wrong?

Thanks.

Comment: Cost you post the rest of your config? Your options worked fine for me

Answer (score 0):

I was using Sinatra for my Site-A, and figured that Sinatra was appending SAMEORIGIN for X-Frame-Options. I had to disable frame options as:

```
set :protection, except: :frame_options
```

to get things working.